# How to give small voltage signal to Arduino?

Tags: voltage, analog, sound, arduino-uno, small-signal

I have a device which audibly says a specific line, let's say it says "received payment of $5," and the device has a speaker connected. Now I want when it says this line, my Arduino should start my motor connected to one pin. The problem is speaker voltage is very low; somewhere around 10 mV and the Arduino will only accept 5 V. How can I deal with this situation?

Comment: "pin" is not an acronym and should not be written in all caps. It's just a regular word.

Comment: _"The problem is speaker voltage is very low; somewhere around 10 mV"_ That seems highly unlikely. How did you measure it?

Answer (score 1):

A speaker signal is Much More than only 10mV. You probably used a 50Hz-60Hz electricity voltmeter instead of an audio voltmeter.
A microphone signal is only 10mV.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to detect the presence or absence of an AC signal of amplitude 10mV, and produce a 5V/0V digital signal to represent that.

10mV is very low, and may require amplification before any "detection", but I suggest you try this first:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsbfKg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

<sub>Note: Don't install D3, it's only here to get the simulation to accurately model the LM393's open collector. Replace D3 with a direct connection.</sub>

VR1 allows you adjust sensistivity, by varying slightly the switching threshold voltage of the LM393 comparator. When an AC input signal is present, the LM393's open collector goes low, quickly charging C3 via R8. When there's no signal, C3 discharges very slowly via R9. The result is a digital "low" when there is a signal present at IN.

D2 prevents the output going negative when the power supply disappears, and allows C3 to discharge quickly and harmlessly when that happens.

This circuit is very sensitive, and might react to noise on the power supply, which is why I opted to use zener diode D1 to provide a stable 3.6V, from which I derive all bias potentials.

Example input (top) and output (bottom):

[image]
[image]

It's very difficult to work with input signals of the order of 10mV, with any certainty of performance. If you find that the circuit triggers sporadically, even with no input signal, then you'll have to amplify the input signal first, and reduce the sensitivity of this stage.

Answer (score 0):

This would be easily accomplished with an op-amp, but it can also be done with a transistor. It should be possible to get an output for a logic high, but this gets 800 mV from a 10 mV (peak) 1 kHz sine wave.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQQFgg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: Audio amplifier]

Answer (score 0):

You could use an ADS1115. It has 16-bit resolution, and unlike the built-in 10-bit ADC on the Arduino, it should have no problem measuring a 10mV signal. This is a much used device, and your search engine of choice will find several excellent hookup guides in a jiffy.